# Finding the Closest Divisable in an Array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am having an Array of `N` integer where `N<= 10^6` for `every index i` i have to find the closest left neighbor of i such that `A[j]%A[i]==0 0<j<i`

Example

```
3 4 2 6 7 3

Nearest Neighbor array 
-1 -1 1 -1 -1 3

As for last element i.e 3 6%3==0 and index of 6 is 3 so ans is 3
similar for 2 nearest neighbor is 4
```

**Brute Force Approach**

```
int[] Neg = new int[n];
Arrays.fill(Neg,-1);
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
  if(A[j]%A[i]==0){
    Neg[i]=j;
  break;
}
```

This `O(n^2) approach and will fail` how can i come up with a better approach probably O(nlogn)

Comment: What's the maximum possible value of the array element?

Comment: Are there any limits for the values in your "Array of integers"? Or whole integer range of `-2^31.. 2^31 - 1`

Comment: @Aivean  Value are in range 1 to 10^6

Comment: @dreamzor it is 10^6

Comment: You said `N <= 10^6`. But what about `A[i]`. Is it true that `1 <= A[i] <= 10^6`? If so, it would help to add that information to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple O(n.sqrt(n)) algorithm as follows:

```
Initialize an array D to all -1.
For i = 1,2,...,n
   Let a = A[i]
   Output D[a]
   For each divisor d of A[i]:
       set D[d] = i
```

You can find all the divisors of a number in O(sqrt(n)) with a simple loop, or you may find it faster to do some precomputing of factorizations.

The algorithm works by using D[x] to store the position j of the most recent number A[j] that is a multiple of x.

Comment: what if `A[j]%A[i]==k` where k is constant

Comment: Modify the algorithm to compute divisors of A[i]-k instead